# EJB 3.1: Kick off asynchronous task in stateless bean

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I have a `@Stateless` bean where a method needs to return a status quickly but perform a long running task in a background thread. My approach has been to do the following:

Create a thread pool for executing these tasks, and make the threadpool a member variable:

```
final ExecutorService m_threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5 /* Get from config*/, new ThreadFactory()
{
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "NotificationInputHandler Thread");
    }
});
```

Split my service method into two parts: 1) createStatus and 2) performBigTask

```
public Result process(final List<String> input) {
    final Result status = createStatus(input)
    m_threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            performBigTask(input);
        }
    });
    return status;
}
```

My questions are:
1. Could this be done in a better way?
2. I am running on JBoss 7. Is there an app-server provided thread pool I could inject instead of instantiating my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use @Asynchronous , have an other stateless session B bean to do your big task and annotate its method with @Asynchronous and then have you original session Bean lets call it A call before it returns the status

**B:**

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<SomeResult> performBigTask(List<String> input){
/*run your big task*/
return new Asynchronous<SomeResult>(bigTaskResult);}
```

**A:**

```
@EJB B b;
public Result process(final List<String> input) {
final Result status = createStatus(input)
Future<SomeResult>result= b.performBigTask(input);
//check if every thing went well or what ever logic you have 
return status;
}
```

if you want to see how to manipulate Future here is a link [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @achabahe! How do I control the characteristics of the threadpool in Jboss? Specifically, I would like to control number of threads and the queue size for the task backlog.

Comment: Also, does this have to be a separate bean or can the @Asynchronous method live on the same bean?

Comment: Oh JBoss doesn't respect the specification 100% it has a Utility calss that will help you retrieve a proxy for that session bean then you can use that proxy , and to retrieve the result of the call you also use the Utility class to retrieve Future<SomeResult> to be used about the configuration i realy don't know about it

Comment: you can tuneup the EJB pool through JBOSS admin console i think Jboss would have this feature

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out JBoss documentation for this.